# How to configure Webpack for multiple html files with common js and html specific js?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have setup an [angular 2 version rc5 with webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#development-configuration) project.
I am trying to add some extras like a lib.ts (for custom libraries not angular dependant) and redirect.html page which will be used as a callback page by third party for authentication (say Dropbox). so my webpack.common.js now looks like

```
 entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts',
    'lib': './src/lib.ts'
 },
 plugins: [
     new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
         name: ['app', 'lib', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
     }),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         filename:'index.html'
         template: 'src/index.html'
     }),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         filename:'dropbox.html'
         template: 'src/redirect.html',
         excludeChunks:['app']
     })
 ]
```

This redirect page is just a normal page (not an angular page) which captures access_token using lib.ts and lib.ts is also used by angular as a service which pretty much wraps libs.ts.

Now i want to add a script tag or file only for redirect.html and not for angular or index.html how do i do that? Is there an example which deals with two or more separate html files with some common js includes mixed with some unique html specific js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing, I used ejs filetype as template

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'dropbox.html',
  template: 'src/redirect.ejs',
  chunks:['polyfills','dropbox','lib'],
  //model for ejs
  redirectPage:'Dropbox'
})
```

then inside dropbox.template.ejs

```
<script>
  var redirectPage = '<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.redirectPage %>';//'Dropbox'
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the CopyWebpackPlugin to copy a separate static html and js file which is used for the callback https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin

So your webpack file would be something like this

```
plugins: [
 new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
     name: ['app', 'lib', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
 }),
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     filename:'index.html'
     template: 'src/index.html'
 }),
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { context: "src/dropbox", from: "**/*" }
 ])
]
```

Where in src/dropbox you put the callback dropbox.html and dropbox_lib.js. This code will put these two files in the root dist. So you should be able to hit http://example.com/dropbox.html

I haven't figured out how to put the css used in the main angular app into this html file.

PS I'm pretty new to webpack